# JsDoc: How do I document that an object can have arbritrary (unknown) properties but with a particular type?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

This is a similar to [question 30360391](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/30360391). I want to express that the parameter of a function is a plain JS object that can have arbitrary properties (with unknown) names but all properties are objects themselves with fixed properties.

An example: The function is just like this

```
/**
 * @param {Descriptor} desc
 */
function foo( desc ) {
  // ...
}
```

and a typical `desc` looks like

```js
desc = {
  unknownEntity1: {
    priority: 5,
    writable: false,
  },
  unknownEntity2: {
    priority: 42,
    writable: true,
  },
  unknownEntity3: {
    priority: 9,
    writable: false,
  }
}
```

I already have

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} DescriptorEntry
 * @property {number} priority - The priority of the entity
 * @property {boolean} writable - True, if the entity can be modified
 */
```

I still need a `typedef` for `Descriptor` that basically express that Descriptor is an object with arbitrary properties but all of type `DescriptorEntry`. As pseudo-code it would be something like

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Descriptor
 * @property {DescriptorEntry} *
 */
```

Of course, the asterisk `*` as a wildcard for "any property" is invalid Jsdoc syntax. But how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 17):

Per https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html , as of JSDoc 3.2, JSDoc has had full support of Google Closure Compiler type expressions. One such format is described at https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html#jsdoc-types :

```
{Object.<string, number>}
```

So in your case, you should be able to do:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object.<string, DescriptorEntry>} Descriptor
 */
```

or just:

```
/**
 * @typedef {{string, DescriptorEntry}} Descriptor
 */
```

You could even replace `string` in the above examples with its own type, if you wanted to have a special type called `DescriptorName` or such and detailing the allowable string values.

One note, however. In my case at least, while JSDoc is not rejecting the latter format, at least with the default template, it is only showing it as an "Object" without any special details. The first format is shown correctly, however.

Comment: This doesn't work in PHPStorm as of 2020.3.1. I still get the "Possible iteration over custom/inherited properties" diagnostic when I do `for(let key in desc)`.

Comment: Today one may reference https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html, as http://usejsdoc.org/ is no longer.

Answer (score 2):

These are Typescript Interfaces for `PropertyDescriptor` and `PropertyDescriptorMap`. (They are also used by PhpStorm 2020 for code completion):
[TypeScript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/87fd1827f2f2f3dafa76c14f13b9defc69481766/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L107-L118)

```js
interface PropertyDescriptor {
    configurable?: boolean;
    enumerable?: boolean;
    value?: any;
    writable?: boolean;
    get?(): any;
    set?(v: any): void;
}

interface PropertyDescriptorMap {
    [s: string]: PropertyDescriptor;
}
```

You could either use them directly as `@type {}` or re-define both:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} PropertyDescriptor
 * @property {function(v: *): void} [set]             - Set [name](v){...}      'accessor descriptor' only
 * @property {function(): *}        [get]             - Get [name](){...}       'accessor descriptor' only
 * @property {undefined|*}          [value]           - Value (primitive|func)  valid in 'data descriptor' only
 * @property {undefined|boolean}    [writable]        - Writable                valid in 'data descriptor' only
 * @property {undefined|boolean}    [configurable]    - Configurable            valid in 'data && accessor - descriptor'
 * @property {undefined|boolean}    [enumerable]      - Enumerable              valid in 'data && accessor - descriptor'
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object<string,PropertyDescriptor>} PropertyDescriptorMap
 */

/**
 *  @type {PropertyDescriptor} myDescriptor
 */
let myDescriptor = {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    // value: {},
    // writable: true,
    get myGet(){},
    set myGet(v){}
};
```