# How to use jdoc to describe a function that receive a complex object with dynamic properties like a json schema

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Example:

```
/**
*
* @param {any} data - Object to be validated
* @params {Object} schema - JSON schema
* @params {Object} schema.properties - JSON schema properties
* ** @params {string} schema.properties[any].type - field property type ???**
*/
function validate(data, schema) {
}
```

similiar to [JsDoc: How do I document that an object can have arbritrary (unknown) properties but with a particular type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702398/jsdoc-how-do-i-document-that-an-object-can-have-arbritrary-unknown-properties)

[JSDoc Object of templated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360391/jsdoc-object-of-templated-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {{properties: Object.<string, {type: string}>}} schema
 */
function validate(data, schema) {
    schema.properties['test'].type = 'test';
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind not being compatible with the Closure Compiler
(it still works in WebStorm):

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Property
 * @property {string} type
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Schema
 * @property {Object.<string, Property>} properties
 */

/**
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {Schema} schema
 */
function validate(data, schema) {
    schema.properties['test'].type = 'test';
}
```

See:

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html#jsdoc-types

Comment: Today one may reference https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html, as http://usejsdoc.org/ is no longer.